# Is there a way to install GCL in centos?

Tags: centos, common-lisp

installing [GCL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gcl/) to Centos
anybody can help?
we use CentOS 6.5
thanks,

Comment: i think GCL is not available on Centos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly what you're looking for, but you could try sbcl (Steel Bank Common Lisp) from the rhel-epel repo.